# Moderator for thread, please

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation

User Amin has added a question as an answer. Amin needs a new thread, imho.

[How do you create a parameterized query in MS Access 2003 and use other queries/forms to fill the parameters and obtain a resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95277/how-do-you-create-a-parameterized-query-in-ms-access-2003-and-use-other-queries-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you flag the post a moderator will see it; there's no need to post in meta about it.